# how to set proper domain for date time scale in d3

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js

Am trying to build a scatter plot with the following data:

```
[
{"frequency": 10, "date": "2014-01-01"},
{"frequency": 20, "date": "2014-01-02"},
{"frequency": 30, "date": "2014-01-03"}
]
```

Am plotting "date" on x-axis and frequency on y-axis. Am using "d3.time.scale" on x-axis. The problem is scale and ticks start on x-axis right from origin and because of this i get plots starting right on my y-axis.

In order to solve this, i tried adding the day before and day after i.e., "2013-12-31" & "2014-01-04" to the x-axis domain (using "d3.time.day.offset" function).

The above code works if given time series are in days intervals. If my data is in months interval like this:

```
 [
{"frequency": 10, "date": "2014-01-01"},
{"frequency": 20, "date": "2014-02-02"},
{"frequency": 30, "date": "2014-03-03"}
]
```

The above code will not work. I have to use "d3.time.month.offset" function instead.

Is there a way to know what interval the given time series is in and use the appropriate offset. (i.e., "d3.time.month.offset", "d3.time.year.offset", "d3.time.day.offset", etc).

Thanks

Comment: You could try calling `.nice()` on the scale after setting the domain and see if that works for you.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Tried that. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem, but I think this may be useful: http://jsfiddle.net/robdodson/KWRxW/

`var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(data[0].date), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].date), 1)])
    .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);`

Also, Mike enumerates on Date/Time offsets here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals

:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cross browser solution:

```
var timeFormat = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S');
```

which will return a cross-browser-consistent Date object when used to set the domain of the scale:

```
.domain([timeFormat.parse('2014-03-08T12:00:00'), timeFormat.parse('2014-03-10T00:00:00')])
```

See http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/9671241 for more information